# Migrate geolocation field

Tags: 8, migrations

I have gone through the /upgrade gui part on my website.  However the geo location fields have not copied across.

Am I correct in thinking that instead of manually entering the data again, I could:

1. Create the field (same name) and add it to the content types I was using.
2. Export the field_data_field_location
3. Import both these fields into the Drupal 8 database as field_revision_field_location respectively?

As far I can see the tables are pretty similar, although there are same number of fields 2 of them are different.

- The D7 Table has a field entity_type
- The D8 Table has field_location_data

I will attach the schema for both tables.

D7:

```
+------------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field                  | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| entity_type            | varchar(128)     | NO   | PRI |         |       |
| bundle                 | varchar(128)     | NO   | MUL |         |       |
| deleted                | tinyint(4)       | NO   | PRI | 0       |       |
| entity_id              | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| revision_id            | int(10) unsigned | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| language               | varchar(32)      | NO   | PRI |         |       |
| delta                  | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| field_location_lat     | double           | NO   | MUL | 0       |       |
| field_location_lng     | double           | NO   | MUL | 0       |       |
| field_location_lat_sin | double           | NO   |     | 0       |       |
| field_location_lat_cos | double           | NO   |     | 0       |       |
| field_location_lng_rad | double           | NO   |     | 0       |       |
+------------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

D8:

```
+------------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field                  | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| bundle                 | varchar(128)     | NO   | MUL |         |       |
| deleted                | tinyint(4)       | NO   | PRI | 0       |       |
| entity_id              | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| revision_id            | int(10) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
| langcode               | varchar(32)      | NO   | PRI |         |       |
| delta                  | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| field_location_lat     | double           | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| field_location_lng     | double           | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| field_location_lat_sin | double           | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| field_location_lat_cos | double           | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| field_location_lng_rad | double           | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| field_location_data    | longblob         | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+------------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

All help and advice appreicated!

Mark.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was using the wrong version of geolocation.  If you use the 8.x-1.11 when you run the upgrade script it pull over the geolocation data into your system.  Although this isn't the default that composer installed for me, I had to re-install it.

Hope it helps someone out there,

Mark.